# Performance testing with custom summaryFunction

Tags: r, performance-testing, cross-validation, r-caret

I'm tuning parameters with custom `summaryFunction` in caret.

I originally thought that if I set K-fold cross validation and input data has N points, performance will be measured with N/K data points.

However, apparently it seems not correct because when I extract `data$pred` by using `browser()` which is the handed data to summary function, it only had 10 data.
Since the input(`df`) has over 500 data points, this number is way smaller than my expectation.

Why does it only have 10 data? Is there any way to increase this?(=performance testing with more large data points)

Any kind of help is needed. Thank you.

```
sigma.list <- seq(1, 5, 1)
c.list <- seq(1, 10, 1)
met <- "FValue"

#define evaluation function
eval <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL){
  mat <- table(data$pred, data$obs)
  pre <- mat[1,1]/sum(mat[1,]) #precision
  rec <- mat[1,1]/sum(mat[,1]) #recall
  res <- c("Precision"=pre, "Recall"=rec, "FValue"=2*pre*rec/(pre+rec))
  browser()
  res
}
#define train control
tc <-  trainControl(method = "cv",
                    number = 5,
                    summaryFunction = eval,
                    classProbs = TRUE,
                    )

#tune with caret
svm.tune <- train(Flag~.,
                   data = df,
                   method = "svmRadial",
                   tuneGrid = expand.grid(C=c.list, sigma=sigma.list),
                   trControl = tc,
                   metric = met
                   )
```

Comment: I just observed the same. It appears that `caret`'s first call to `summaryFunction` (you called it `eval`) passes a `data.frame` with only ten samples the first time. If you continue debugging, you'll see the next call has the correct amount of samples. I'm not sure why this occurs, will have to look into the `caret` source code unfortunately. Will update you if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

After tracking this down, it appears this is normal `caret` behavior.

I think that `caret` is essentially verifying that your summaryFunction is working properly by passing fake data (of length 10) to it. The function inside `caret` that is doing this is `evalSummaryFunction`.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing in the RStudio's debugger but this code in `train.default`:

```
  testSummary <- evalSummaryFunction(y, wts = weights, 
    ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, metric = metric, 
    method = method)
  perfNames <- names(testSummary)
```

calls `evalSummaryFunction` which looks like:

```
function (y, wts = NULL, perf = NULL, ctrl, lev, metric, method) 
{
  n <- if (class(y)[1] == "Surv") 
    nrow(y)
  else length(y)
  if (class(y)[1] != "Surv") {
    if (is.factor(y)) {
      values <- rep_len(levels(y), min(10, n))
      pred_samp <- factor(sample(values), levels = lev)
      obs_samp <- factor(sample(values), levels = lev)
    }
    else {
      pred_samp <- sample(y, min(10, n))
      obs_samp <- sample(y, min(10, n))
    }
  }
  else {
    pred_samp <- y[sample(1:n, min(10, n)), "time"]
    obs_samp <- y[sample(1:n, min(10, n)), ]
  }
  testOutput <- data.frame(pred = pred_samp, obs = obs_samp)
  if (!is.null(perf)) {
    if (is.vector(perf)) 
      stop("`perf` should be a data frame", call. = FALSE)
    perf <- perf[sample(1:nrow(perf), nrow(testOutput)), 
      , drop = FALSE]
    testOutput <- cbind(testOutput, perf)
  }
  if (ctrl$classProbs) {
    for (i in seq(along = lev)) testOutput[, lev[i]] <- runif(nrow(testOutput))
    testOutput[, lev] <- t(apply(testOutput[, lev], 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))
  }
  else {
    if (metric == "ROC" & !ctrl$classProbs) 
      stop("train()'s use of ROC codes requires class probabilities. See the classProbs option of trainControl()")
  }
  if (!is.null(wts)) 
    testOutput$weights <- sample(wts, min(10, length(wts)))
  testOutput$rowIndex <- sample(1:n, size = nrow(testOutput))
  ctrl$summaryFunction(testOutput, lev, method)
}
```

It appears that 10 is the length of fake data `caret` passes to your summary function to evaluate it (make sure it is working properly?).

If anyone can verify/explain better that this is what `caret` is actually doing, please post.

Comment: Thank you very much for your debugging. I really appreciate it since that was way beyond my skill. Still not sure why "10", but hopefully someone can answer this in the future. Thank you again for your analysis.

Comment: @MPO I believe it is 10 because humans have ten fingers usually. In other words, it's just an arbitrary test of your custom `summaryFunction`, to let you know if there is any issue with it (rather than later getting some cryptic error message).

Comment: Thank you for following up. I understand that the number 10 doesn't mean anything. I am sorry to ask this since it's such a basic question, but how do I properly train the model with my custom eval. function? Because 'data$pred' only had 10 data, I assume the model was trained with fake data in my code. (which means the model is garbage?) Thank you in advance for your kindness.